# Array unsetting keys

Tags: php, arrays

Straight to the point...

I have an array (`$is_anonymous_ary`) that looks like this:

```
array (
  [80] => 1
  [57] => 1
  [66] =>
  [60] => 
  [90] => 1
)
```

And another array (`$user_id_ary`) like this one:

```
array (
  [0] => 80
  [1] => 30
  [2] => 57
  [3] => 89
  [4] => 66
  [5] => 60
  [6] => 90
)
```

I need to unset values on the `$user_id_ary` based on the first array. So, if the value from `$is_anonymous_ary` is 1 (true), then take the key from that array, check against `$user_id_ary`, and unset the keys from `$user_id_ary` which had the value from the keys from `$is_anonymous_ary`.

I complicated the description a bit, here is how I need my final result:

```
user_id_ary = array(
  [0] => 30
  [1] => 89
  [2] => 66
  [3] => 60
)
```

As you see all keys from the `$is_anonymous_ary` that had a `TRUE` value, are gone in the second array. which had the keys from the first array as values in the second array.

Hope I made myself clear.

Comment: Can't this be done with a simple loop based intersect to remove based on `===` 1?

Comment: I don't know, hence this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try **[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)**:

```
$user_id_ary = array_filter($user_id_ary, function($var) use ($is_anonymous_ary) {
  return !(isset($is_anonymous_ary[$var]) && $is_anonymous_ary[$var] === 1);
});
```

Comment: Why return? I am not working inside a function! Can you explain what your code does?

Comment: @Dugi Have you checked the manual? The element make the callback return false will be removed.

Comment: @Dugi The return decides whether to filter the array based on that condition or not. `array_filter`, without the function, will remove null values, with this function will remove based where the index isset and it `===` 1

Comment: Your answer worked after changing the identical comparison to `==`. Thanks.

Comment: @Dugi That means it's string `'1'` not integer `1` in your array.

Comment: True, they are not integers, but booleans.

Comment: @Dugi If it's a boolean, then you could omit `=== true`

Comment: @xdazz Can you provide a PHP 5.2- example? This code works on PHP 5.3+ only. These closures are driving me crazy nowadays, my host filled my PHP error log.

Comment: @Dugi For PHP 5.2, use array_filter will have to write more code. Just use a loop instead as suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

How easy:)

```
$new_array =NULL;
foreach($is_anonymous_ary as $key=>$value){

  $new_array[] = array_search($key, $user_id_ary);
  unset($is_anonymous_ary[$key]);
}
$user_id_ary =  $new_array;
```

Comment: I need to keep working with $user_id_ary as the variable name, since it's used in more places than once. Any suggestion that doesn't get rid of my current $user_id_ary?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($user_id_ary as $id){
   if($is_anonymous_ary[$id] == '1'){
      unset($d);
   }       
}
```

if this wont work, try to iterate thru each elem in user_id_array

Answer (score 0):

```
$user_id_ary = array_diff($user_id_ary, array_keys(array_filter($is_anonymous_ary)));
```